# Calling jQuery function with JSON set in anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I am trying to render a JSON object on a JSP in an anchor  tag of an accordion on click of which a jQuery function should be called. This jQuery function then opens up that accordion.

This is the jQuery function:

```
 function accordion(){
        $('.mrc-accordion .columns > ul > li > a').click(function(e){
            if(!$(this).parents('li').hasClass('active')){
                $(this).parents('li').addClass('active').children('section').slideToggle();
            }else{
                $(this).parents('li').removeClass('active').children('section').slideToggle();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        })
    }
```

This is the JSP code :

```
<div class="mrc-accordion  mrc-accorweb mrc-newsRoom">
.
.
.
<ul id="somerandom">
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I am rendering the JSON object like this:

```
var webcastsListing =  document.getElementById('somerandom');
jsonString=getFormattedJson(webcast);
webcastsListing.innerHTML = jsonString;

function getFormattedJson(webcast) {
    var temp = '<li><a href="#">'+webcast.title+'</a><section><ul class="mrc-contactDetail webcast"><li><p>'+webcast.description+'</p></li></ul></section></li>';
    return temp;
}
```

The jsonString object that is being created is given below:

```
<li><a href="#">Mercer Webcasts 2014 First Detail page</a><section><ul class="mrc-contactDetail webcast"><li><p>Mercer Webcasts 2014 First Detail page description</p></li></ul></section></li>
```

It sets up in the `<ul id="somerandom"></ul>` nicely like :

```
<ul id="somerandom"><li><a href="#">Mercer Webcasts 2014 First Detail page</a><section><ul class="mrc-contactDetail webcast"><li><p>Mercer Webcasts 2014 First Detail page description</p></li></ul></section></li></ul>
```

but when I click on the anchor tag, the function accordion() doesn't gets called. While if I set the code snippet manually:

```
 <li><a href="#">Mercer Webcasts 2014 First Detail page</a><section><ul class="mrc-contactDetail webcast"><li><p>Mercer Webcasts 2014 First Detail page description</p></li></ul></section></li>
```

inside `<ul id="somerandom"></ul>` in the JSP, I can see the function being called on click of anchor as expected and the accordion works as expected. I am not able to understand why the function accordion() is not getting called when I do the same thing using Javascript and JSON.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the events handlers are applied before you can add the markup from JSON.
Whereas, when you add the markup manually, the anchor tag and other elements are already present on the DOM when event handlers are applied. You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Call `accordion()` after you've populated the `ul` element from the JSON string; or
2. Using [jQuery `on` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/) as follows:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.mrc-accordion .columns > ul > li > a', function(event) {
       if(!$(this).parents('li').hasClass('active')) {
           $(this).parents('li').addClass('active').children('section').slideToggle();
       } else {
           $(this).parents('li').removeClass('active').children('section').slideToggle();
       }
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   });
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reason and the suggestion, the second method just worked fine. Just for the info. how can I make sure that the accordion() function is called after the ul element is populated from the JSON string.

Comment: Call `accordion();` after `webcastsListing.innerHTML = jsonString;` and it should work just fine.